# A word for someone who shows great interest/love for something that they know very little about

Tags: single-word-requests, vocabulary

I'm searching for such a word so I can use it for myself. I'm still young and I sadly have numerous passions for many things but sometimes find myself at a loss, for I know very little in the subject, and I can't find the time to learn all about my interests. Please help me find the word to describe this.

Comment: You may, for example be an *avid* golfer, even if you can hardly hit the ball, since "avid" simply means having great enthusiasm for the sport.

Comment: You might need more than one word to convey the idea accurately. You are a passionate novice, an enthusiastic abecedarian, an unschooled aficionado, an eager newbie, a fan on the sidelines. If you learn a little of each of your passions, but never gain full expertise, you're a jack of all trades, master of none.

Comment: Like, getting married ?

Comment: I would use an "enthusiast."

Answer (score 2):

amateurish

dilettante

upstart

self-deprecating

Comment: How does 'upstart' qualify to be here?

Comment: Maybe it's a stretch -- but here's a definition that gives a bit of the feel I was thinking of: "characteristic of someone who has risen economically or socially but lacks the social skills appropriate for this new position" (see http://upstart.askdefinebeta.com/).  The lack of skills part is what I was thinking about, I suppose.

Comment: Ooh -- ooh -- dabbler!

Comment: Dilettante is created specifically for this situation. A person who knows a little bit about a topic that they find delight in.

Answer (score 1):

You are **aspiring**.

> **aspiring** |əˈspī(ə)riNG|
> adjective [ attrib. ] –
> directing one's hopes or ambitions toward becoming a specified type of person: *an aspiring artist.*

It is uncommon, however, to be "aspiring" full-stop.  If you are aspiring in many areas, you could use **aspirant**.

> **aspirant** |ˈaspərəntəˈspīrənt|
> adjective [ attrib. ] –
> (of a person) having ambitions to achieve something, typically to follow a particular career: *an aspirant politician.*

Both of these terms imply that you *will* one day be skilled, but you're just not there yet.

If you're talking about a hobby or activity for which you expect or intend little improvement, I would use **"enthusiastic"**.  When I tell people, "I'm very passionate about basketball, but very terrible at it," they often respond with, "So, you're *enthusiastic*."

Of course, it only works in some contexts.  Alone, "enthusiastic" does not imply adeptness or its lacking.

> **enthusiastic** noun – having or showing intense and eager enjoyment, interest, or approval

But in a case where skill is being questioned, then it's a great way to imply an absence of ability. For example, it would work if "enthusiastic" is used to substitute "talented" or "good".

> A: "Is George a talented dancer?"
>
> B: "Well, George is an enthusiastic dancer."

This is a kind way of saying "no".  The two qualities aren't mutually exclusive, but *B* answered a yes-or-no question by correcting "talented" to "enthusiastic".  *A* should understand now that George may never be a good dancer, but he likes dancing.  "Eager," "passionate," and "keen" also work here.

Answer (score 0):

### Neophyte

From the [ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/neophyte):

> A person who is new to a subject or activity: *four-day cooking classes are offered to neophytes and experts*